Python specify type of object in "for element in arrray:" - style loop
I know in python you can specify the type of an instance like so :
foo : myObject

But I have an instance of an object in a list like this :
for element in array:
   element.callfunction()

and I would like VSCode to recognise that element is of a type that accepts .callfunction() and give me early syntax errors before I try debugging.
Would there be a way to have something like this? :
for element : myObject in array:
   element.callfunction()

Obviously, the above doesn't work, but is there something similar I'm just missing?

Are you sure you need to annotate the variable? If you declare the type of the array elements, type checkers will automatically infer the type of element.
